# Excel table in an outlook email

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook

I am trying to send an excel table in an email (not as an attachment I want the recipient to see the table as soon as they open the email). However I also want the recipient to be able to fill in the fields of the table, in the email and send it back.

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: I understand your question, but I'm guessing a normal paste didn't work? You need to provide things you tried unsuccessfully to probably get a better answer. See https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We need to know the nature of the table.  Is it just text and data entry locations or does it need to contain formulas?  If recipients will be entering data and replying, how will you be extracting the entries for your use?  Does the embedded table need to be created in Excel or do you just need some mechanism to capture reader input and return it in a usable form?  For example, are you aware of Outlook's ability to use forms and conduct "surveys" (http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=63)?

Answer (score 0):

You just copy & paste it (or paste special via the arrow under paste)? If they were to reply the should be able to put values in empty rows & columns and/or create new ones. This works for a basic table, if you have advanced formulas or functions then it'll likely not work & you have to attach the Excel file. I think you need to explain further on the things you have tried & why they didn't work to get a better answer